# useEffect cleanup function not working with history.push()

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have issue with `useEffect` cleanup function. I always get warning:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
> in Login (created by ConnectFunction)
> in ConnectFunction (at App.js:119)
> in component (created by Context.Consumer)

But in my code there is no any state update:

```
useEffect( () => {
        let mounted = false
        // Check is user logged in and redirects to dashboard
        if (userData !== null && !mounted) {
            if (userData.type === 'employee') {
                history.push(`/${agency}/dashboard/${userUID}`)
            } else if (userData.type === 'crewagency') {
                history.push(`/${agency}/crew-dashboard/`)
            } else if ( userData.type === 'keyagency') {
                history.push(`/${agency}/key-dashboard/`)
            }
        }
        return () => mounted = true

    }, [agency, history, userData, userUID])
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the `mounted` variable? `useEffect` runs after the component is mounted by default. The cleanup function has no meaning here, because `mounted` is not a state variable or something that survives re-renders.

Answer (score 0):

This function has no chance to return, since you `history.push` earlier. Like @BlackMath said, what are you trying to acheive with this `mounted` variable anyway?

Comment: I always get this error, and I added cleanup function to remove this error, but it doesn't work, I still get this error, and can't understand why